# Spouse with Danish residence permit's proofs necessary to apply my tourist Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, residency

Me and my wife have planned a Europe trip with Italy being the main Destination.

She is in Denmark presently and hold's a Danish residence permit which will be valid for our tour duration, she does not need a seperate Schengen visa to travel other Schengen countries

As our main destination is Italy, I plan to apply for a Schengen visa in Italian Embassy. (I am presently in India and we plan to meet in Europe before we proceed on our trip)

Will I need to provide my wife's Danish residence permit as one of the documents in my application while applying for my Italian tourist visa?

The reason I ask is all the hotel reservations and Europe internal travel tickets have both our names.

Comment: Since she has a permit, it wouldn't hurt, I guess, to copy it and present as an additional document...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my Italy tourist visa approved today with Multiple entry option for 15 days for a 30 day period.

I did include all the details about wife in the cover letter and included copies of her residence permit and deputation letter from her Indian employer, her flight tickets as well as additional the documents.

Answer (score 2):

It would not add anything to your application eligibility - consider the opposite though - it may raise a flag that this person is actually going there under the pretense of tourism to stay with his wife.

I think you should consider the application solely on your eligibility as a tourist to visit Italy for the duration of your trip; as your wife is not accompanying you from India but is rather meeting you there.

Comment: Agreed, but what if questions crop up regarding accommodations and tickets bookings made for both of us? As there is no interview for a tourist visa I guess the documents take care of any doubts that arise,,please let me know your thoughts

Comment: What ticket bookings? All you need to show are bookings from India - Italy - India; and the hotel reservations.